# BIOS shows RAM frequency and type incorrectly

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, bios, performance

I have a PC, that I used for three years, it worked fine. I have not been using since the last 8 months, and it seems the computer is very slow. It seems for somehow the computer memory runs at 400 MHz. The RAM is 1600 Mhz and it used to work OK, from the BIOS I can either set Auto or 933 Mhz highest. When I select 933 Mhz, it shows correctly 1600 MHz, but it shows it as an SDRAM, but I have an DDR3.

Here is the output

```
sudo lshw -short -C memory       
H/W path                   Device     Class       Description
=============================================================
/0/0                                  memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4/5                                memory      192KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                                memory      4MiB L2 cache
/0/4/7                                memory      4MiB L3 cache
/0/26                                 memory      8GiB System Memory
/0/26/0                               memory      DIMM [empty]
/0/26/1                               memory      8GiB DIMM Synchronous 400 MHz
```

and th ouput of

```
inxi -Fxz

           Desktop: Cinnamon 4.2.3 Distro: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: M5A78L-M LX3 v: Rev X.0x serial: <filter> BIOS: American Megatrends v: 1401 
           date: 05/05/2016 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: AMD FX-4300 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Bulldozer L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 30536 
           Speed: 1396 MHz min/max: 1400/3800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1405 2: 1395 3: 1410 4: 1423
```

I am fairly sure that there is something with the BIOS, I updated it to the latest one, still persists. Interestingly, when I put into DIMM Slot 1, it shows 633 Mhz, and 400 Mhz when put in slot 2.

I cannot even play videos since this slowness, or even when I am writing this post, the letters lag behind.

I tried to take out the batter of motherboard, and put back again, nothing changes.

When I take out off battery and run without batter, I get the following:

[image]

It seems the **BIOS correctly identifies** RAM as 1600 Mhz, but is this a Linux problem? I really do not get it.

Comment: Please post relevant photos from BIOS setup. (You can [edit] the question)

Comment: @gronostaj updated the post with the picture

Comment: That's odd... DDR3-XXXX uses a clock that is half of the XXXX number. So DDR3-1600 should use 800 MHz. 993 MHz (aka DDR3-1866) might work, as some DDR3-1600 modules can have a little overclock margin. But your bios DOES recognize it as DDR-1600. Could be the lshw output just isn't correct because Linux can't properly identify the hardware. It still should have any effect on the overal system speed. I wonder if the real problem is something else.... Like a slowly dying harddisk.

Comment: @Tonny I removed the HDD. Installed a brand new SSD, same problem. I also started from live usb Reborn OS, it works faster, but it also shows 667 Mhz.